# multiple records within a single div tag

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am binding the selected values of autocomplete box into a div tag as

```
var data = "<div class='close'><table><tr><td rowspan='4' width='50px;'><img src='" + studentItem.Photo + "' Width='48' Height='48'  /></td><td>" + studentItem.Name + " ( <span class='stuId'>" + studentItem.StudentId + "</span> )</td><td align='right' ><div id='close' class='close16'/></td></tr><tr><td><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>" + studentItem.Email + "</td><td>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td><td>" + studentItem.Mobile + "</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>";
            $('#students').css('background-color', '#FFAA55');
            $("#students").append(data);
```

and its binding the datas and displyaing in the div tag as

[image]

I want the each record should be in a seperate box, for example look at tag box in our stackoverflow

[image]

i want the result should be like this above.......I even tried to include the div script into a table, but it displays the single record in a whole row, and for the second record it comes to the second row,and I tried including the css inline,that also not working... how can I fix this, can anyone help me..

I tried to set the margin and float style to my div tag as

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="10" >
        <div id="students" style="float: left; clear: both; margin: 25px"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

i tried by setting the margin as 25px for testing purpose and now the output is

[image]

just the space coming between the textbox and div not among records within div, how can I fix this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To separate the boxes, use `margin`. To get them to line up side by side, but wrapping, use `float: left` followed by a `clear: both` element, or use `display: inline-block`.

Comment: I tried adding the styles into the div script as u suggested, my code now is <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            <div id="students" style="display: inline-block; margin: 5px"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>.....but it reports some error when I run the application

Comment: @Shanish: we cannot help you with that unless you post what the errors are. Generally, though, CSS will not generate errors if you get it wrong; the only thing that will happen is that the appearance is not exactly the way you want it. Your errors are probably caused by something else.

Comment: @Shanish: The `margin` and `display` should be added to the individual tags, not to their container. If you want the exact appearance of the stack overflow tags, consider using the browser inspection tools to look at how they've solved the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use some other jQuery plugin, then this might be helpful: [jQuery Autosuggest](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

Comment: thanks Sudhir, am not supposed to use plugin, anyhow I shall try

Answer (score 1):

No need to create `<table>` in var data.
You can put `<table>` outside
And every time when you add just add `<td>` in `<table><tr>` tag.

Otherwise used multiple `<div>` according to situation.

```
        <div id="Adddiv" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" >
        </div>

        ===============jQuery============
        var html = "<div id='Adddata'>";
        html += "<a herf='#' style='cursor: pointer;'>";
        html += "<img src='close.png' alt='' /></a>";
        html += "</div>";

        $("#Adddiv").append(html);
```

Comment: thanks Hiren, I dont understand ur code, can u pls explain it

Comment: I have done same thing before. The div "Adddiv" is main div, in which other records are add in single row. with close button. And remaining code is for jquery. Here I generate the html & then append it into 
"adddiv"